# Android Ftp a file from device to a server

Tags: android, ftp, noclassdeffounderror

I would like to send a file from the device to a ftp server.
Im using an emulator Api level 15 Android 4.0.3

I tried this tutorial:
http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=28&cpage=2#comment-40

but i keep getting "could not connect"

Can anyone help me understands how to use this, or help to connect in a different way?

Comment: im using a string like this "111.111.111.111" as host is that ok?

Comment: Maybe u could try this:
http://www.kodejava.org/examples/354.html This worked for me, as it is the same commons-jar as you used :)

Comment: thanks i have the example code, but im keep getting "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadEception" . I have internet premission in the manifest

Comment: try to execute this code in a service instead of in an activty!

Comment: how do i do that? my ftp class is not an activity, and all the methods are static.

Comment: then just start a servce: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html and run those static method ;)